# What does it mean to be calling a dispatch_async within a getter?

Tags: objective-c, properties, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

GCD can be used to manage as a synchronization mechanism by enforcing dispatch_async on setter and dispatch_sync on getter.

Is there a use case for using dispatch_async within a property getter?

Comment: A getter with side effects (generally a _bad_ use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispatch_async` is asynchronous.  Any computed value computed asynchronously will not be available to be returned from the getter.

So, no, you can't use `dispatch_async()` to compute the returned value (which is why you use `dispatch_sync()`).

Doesn't mean there wouldn't be a use for it, though.  Just not for the return value.